# ASP.NET WebForms and jQuery Validation - validate() undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, jquery-validate

I thought the entire purpose of jQuery was to make a developer's life **easier** but ever since I started learning how to use it ~3 months ago it has caused nothing but nightmares for me!

I'm now working on an ASP.NET WebForms app and am trying to use jQuery Validation since the built-in validator controls can't be easily rendered below their input counterparts. That is all I want to do; have an input with an error message that dynamically appears and disappears **underneath** it, but I've been banging my head against a brick wall for 5 hours trying to figure out how to do one, seemingly-incredibly-simple little thing!

I started off with a bunch of `<asp:RegularExpressionValidator>` and `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator>` controls (since you can't do both validations with one control) but didn't like how the error messages displayed inline, to the right of my inputs. So I spent ~2.5 hours trying to make ASP.NET render the damn things with `display: block;`, to no avail.

That's when I remembered a colleague having mentioned the jQuery Validation plugin to me about a month ago...so off I went trying to implement a solution with that. But no matter what I try, Google Chrome v.41 on Windows keeps giving me an "undefined is not a function" error on the `jQuery.validate()` function.

I know what you're thinking: something along the lines of "ASP.NET mangles control IDs...yada yada yada", but I've been using `<pages clientIDMode="Static" />` in my web.config's `<system.web>` section ever since I started this project, so that's not the issue. I'm also 99.999% sure that I'm including the necessary scripts in the correct order, even though some are included in my master page and some in the content page (this shouldn't matter, should it?)

This post is already way too long, so check out [the full code here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sudqmco609arlls/AABxbRRNS9y12jroenZ6Fv5fa?dl=0).

MTIA to anyone who can tell me what the hell is going on here!

Comment: The relevant code should be included in the question, not in a place thay me soon vanish Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: As I said, the post was already pretty lengthy and the full aspx page is **546 lines**...for future reference, do you really want me to include something like that here??? Narrowing it down to an excerpt that shows the problem was impossible since **I didn't know where the problem was**, only that it was **somewhere** within that page.

Comment: @AdrianHHH - I just read the page you linked to and saw this suggestion:
"Divide and conquer. When you have a small amount of code, but the source of the problem is entirely unclear, start removing code a bit at a time until the problem disappears – then add the last part back".
That's how Cristina and I both eventually solved the problem, so I guess I should've done it in the first place and never even posted here. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I debugged your code. The problem is with your comments. Remove your comments from the code, and it will work :)

Comment: LMAO that is uncanny; I just discovered this myself at pretty much the exact same time you did! But thanks anyway ;-) Can't believe I wasted a whole $#@!ing day because of a few silly comments! I've never seen anything like this before...why on Earth would having comments in your code affect JS/JQ in **any** way, let alone making the browser blindly tell me that a function is undefined...I don't understand this **at all!** Anyway thanks for answering and Happy Easter :D

Comment: Also I'd be interested to know how you debugged the code...such a tool would certainly make my life 100x easier! If I just hit F10, F11 or F5 in VS, the page runs without stopping anywhere...did you do it this way with a breakpoint in some initialisation function? If so, what function?

Comment: For the Javascript code, I use the Google Chrome default debugger (Ctrl+Shift+I). But if you have Internet Explorer, you can use Developer Tools (F12). In visual studio, you edit the code inserting the `debugger;` line where you want the debugger to stop, save, and in the browser you hit F5 key to refresh and the debugger should stop there.

Comment: Ahh OK you meant you debugged the JS...yeah I use Chrome's inbuilt dev tools for that as well. But that's how I discovered the undefined error that I mentioned, with no useful information whatsoever...unless I was looking in the wrong place...?

Comment: I started from a simple scenario, a form with only one field, adding the rest of the code until it got the error. It was not something strange to me, it's not the first time when I have this issue in the Web Forms application that the commented lines are not taken into account. But I never figured out why. So in your case, the real problem could be with the `RequiredFieldValidator` tags. Maybe they are incompatible with JQuery validator or something.

Comment: Hmm very interesting...yeah the "remove all code, then add back a section at a time" approach is what finally led me to the answer as well. Very strange how HTML comments can cause such arbitrary effects, but I guess we'll never know the real reason why. Best just to avoid them like the plague!